# Wordpress different archive pages for categories

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have some issues with a Wordpress custom post type and taxonomy of mine. Its created like:

```
        
        register_post_type(
            'programs',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name'          => __( 'Programs', 'programs' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Program', 'programs' ),
                    [.............]

                ),
                'supports' => array(
                    'title',     
                    'editor',   
                    'excerpt',   
                    'thumbnail', 
                    'revisions',   
                ),
                'has_archive'       => true,
                'public'            => true,
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_in_menu'      => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'publicly_queryable'=> true,
                'exclude_from_search'=> false,
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'query_var'         => true,
            )
        );

        }
}   
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types' );



function create_taxonomies() {
    
    register_taxonomy('program-type', 'programs', array(
                'labels' => array ( 
                    'name'              => _x( 'Type', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                    [.............]
                ),
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'query_var'         => true,
                /*'rewrite'  => array( 
                    'slug' => 'programs' ),*/
            )
            );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomies', 0 );
```

But now I have some problems with my single and archive pages. I can't get [www.url.com/programs](http://www.url.com/programs) to list any of the posts. If I try [www.url.com/programs/[program-type]](http://www.url.com/programs/%5Bprogram-type%5D) it won't show any posts either. But [www.url.com/programs/[post]](http://www.url.com/programs/%5Bpost%5D) seems to work like a charm...

I've created custom post types several times before without any problems, but this time I really can't see what has gone wrong. I've tried to rewrite the slug to be the same as the post type. I've tried to  I've tried around a lot but without any luck and now I'm like blind to see anything incorrect.

**EDIT: --------------**

Ok, so when installing the plugin "Custom Post Type Permalinks" I almost get it to work:

- [www.url.com/programs](http://www.url.com/programs) work
- [www.url.com/programs/[program-type]/[post]](http://www.url.com/programs/%5Bprogram-type%5D/%5Bpost%5D) work
- But [www.url.com/programs/[program-type]](http://www.url.com/programs/%5Bprogram-type%5D) doesn't work. It gets redirected to [www.url.com/[program-type]](http://www.url.com/%5Bprogram-type%5D). Any suggestions on why?

Comment: Did you update your permalinks? If you visit Settings > Permalinks (you don't have to save anything), do you see your posts?

Comment: @disinfor yes, I've updated the permalinks a whole bunch of times. Same outcome :/  any other suggestions?

Comment: I've now updated my post with my progress.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this without updating your .htaccess. WordPress wants to make your taxonomy a post slug.